# What is the difference between jQuery live() and liveQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question says it all. Which one is better and when to use what, I never use jQuery live() as I am using liveQuery plugin for a couple of years, I am used to it and still continue using it. But I want to know the subtle differences between the two and when to use each of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "live" function native to jQuery leverages the bubbling of events up the DOM.  The "liveQuery" plugin, by contrast, uses the selector to find elements in the DOM and attach event handlers directly.

In my opinion you're way better off using the "live" function *when possible*, because it involves less DOM traversal etc. For example, hooking event handlers to things throughout a big table can be kind-of slow with liveQuery but not slow at all with "live". There may be some issues (with IE of course) that force you to use liveQuery sometimes, though jQuery 1.4 has improved "live" considerably.

*edit* — **Update: Sep 2017**

At this point, modern versions of jQuery centralize event handler registration in the `.on()` API. Briefly:

```
$(selector).live("event-name", handler);
```

would today be written with `.on()`:

```
$(document).on("event-name", selector, handler);
```

The `.on()` API provides considerably more flexibility than the long-deprecated `.live()` method did, including the option of using any node in the DOM as the delegation point (like the old `.delegate()` did).

Comment: If the table is already in the document when live() is called then there will still be a DOM traversal.  e.g. $("td").live() still finds every td element.

Comment: There's also `.delegate()` now, and that's really a much smarter API overall.

Comment: If "live" is native to jQuery and "liveQuery" is a plug-in, I would prefer to use "live" because when trying to upgrade to a newer version of jQuery, it would potentially be extra work and trouble having to upgrade "liveQuery" as well and making sure that everything is compatible.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya the jQuery `.live()` method has been deprecated for *years*. It should not be used at all, and neither should `.liveQuery()`. It's 2017 now :)

Comment: @Pointy And my job is to upgrade from jQuery 1.3.1 to the latest version of jQuery. I see .livequery() everywhere in the code. It sounds like I should start soon because this might not be a trivial project.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya in modern jQuery, the `.on()` API centralizes all the event handling. I'll extend the answer; it's about time :)

Comment: I know it is time for me to do this upgrade.

Comment: @Pointy As I mentioned, my legacy system uses jQuery 1.3.1. I need to upgrade to a modern version of jQuery. My first step is trying to get rid of the Live Query plugin and use .on() instead. I wanted to use .on() in jQuery 1.3.1 because I do not want everything to break in my site as soon as I make an abrupt switch from jQuery 1.3.1 to 1.7 for example or something newer, but I realized that .on() is only available starting from jQuery 1.7. Do you think it is a good strategy to translate from .livequery() to .live() first, then move to jQuery 1.7, and then continue my migration from there?

Answer (score 3):

As [Pointy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202367/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-livequery-plugin/2202400#2202400), `live()` leverages the bubbling of events up the DOM (event delegation). 
Also, for each `$(selector).live(type, handler)` call, jQuery only calls `handler` on the `$(event.target).closest(selector)` element - that is, the nearest matching ancestor-or-self element of the event target. 
And, of course, `live()` doesn't support anything like `livequery( matchedFn, unmatchedFn )`.

Implications:

- `$(selector).live()` still requires a traversal of the DOM (obviously). 
  However, if you load jQuery and attach live() handlers in the document head then there is no document body to search yet. Similarly if you insert new content into the page.
- `live()` does less work when being configured - it doesn't have to attach handlers to every matched element
- `live()` does more work in handling events - it has to traverse ancestors of the event target, finding elements that match the selector
- `$("div").live()` is different to `$("div").livequery()` as it only works for the closest `div` to the event target
- Similarly, `$("div, p").live()` is different to `$("div").live(); $("p").live();`

Answer (score 1):

liveQuery plugin was created initially, and then was migrated to jQuery itself.

Answer (score 0):

One of the differences is that .live() is native to jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/live/) and .livequery() is a plugin. As you can see at http://api.jquery.com/live/, .live() was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in version 1.9.