# How to attach event to newly created object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My UI consists in a combo box that displays a type of form. The form is then submitted using ajax. The callback displays the whole form again and other information. The problem is that the first submit works, but the second submit does not take into account the changes made in the form field.

- Select Form1 in the list
- Form1 is displayed with empty field
- User fill out the form and submit
- Form1 is displayed again with the information from the user and also other information
- User changes a field value and submit BUT the old data are submitted.

My current jQuery (I use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do stuff when DOM is ready
    var testCaseList = $('#testCaseId');
    testCaseList.live('change', function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'populateSteps.htm',
           type: 'GET',
           data: 'testCaseId=' + $(this).val(),
           success: function(data){
             $('#formContainer').html(data);
             var formId = $('#testCaseForm');
             var validateButton = $('#validateButton');
             validateButton.live('click', function() {
                 // prepare Options Object
                 var options = {
                     url: 'validateTestCase.htm',
                     success:    function(data) {
                         $('#formContainer').html(data);
                     }
                 };
                 // pass options to ajaxForm
                 alert(formId.formSerialize());
                 formId.ajaxSubmit(options);
             });
           }
       });
    });
  });
```

Basically after changing the value in the combo box, a form is displayed and a click event is attached to the form button. The click only submits the form.

I used the live method to attach the event because the form is displayed after each submit. I know it's not very AJAX but I had to do that because of Spring not handling well partial form.

I could do a better job by attaching the event to the newly created form using bind but I don't know where I should put the code. The form is displayed using a JSP, and I tried to put

```
   HTML/JSP code ...    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Attach the event to the form
    }    </script>
```

after the JSP code but the script is not executed.

**EDIT** The script is not executed because my script is wrong: missing );

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // Attach the event to the form
        });    
</script>
```

Now it's working but I still wonder why the `live` binding use the old data from the form.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to bind events to dynamically created objects I use the LiveQuery plugin like this :

```
   $('.zoom').livequery('click' , function(e){
      x = Math.round( e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
      y = Math.round(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
      sendRequest(71609);
   });
```

LiveQuery : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery

Comment: What is the difference with using `live`?

Comment: I honestly do not know, I was just saying that this is what I do. This previous question will probably answer your question though :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202367/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-live-and-livequery-plugin

Comment: @Sydney afaik, livequery() came first, and then jQuery officially implemented this feature via live()

Comment: @Sime and @Sydney, the built in `live` must bind to *an event*. By contrast, `livequery` can be passed a function as its sole parameter, allowing you to execute 'startup code' on dynamically created objects (very cool). For example: `$('div').livequery(function(){console.log('new div');});` In the example given above, however, there is no functional difference.